# define type to equal one of the interface properties

Tags: typescript, types

Lets assume we have an interface:

```js
interface Foo {
  aaa: string
  bbb: SomeType
  ccc: SomeOtherType
  // ... and 100 more
}
```

I would like to define a type, such that it can receive any of the `Foo` interface property types.

Obviously I could do it manually:

```js
type Bar = Foo['aaa'] | Foo['bbb'] // etc.
```

But that is impractical and not DRY, especially with large interfaces.
Is there any better way to define such type, so that it automatically accepts interfaces types?

Comment: `type Bar = Foo[keyof Foo]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can achieve what you want using [mapped types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html#mapped-types):

```
type Bar = Foo[keyof Foo]
```

[Playground.](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAyg9gWwgFXNAvFA3gXwLABQhoksiEA8sABYQBOqpmuhhAlgHbD0BmAhgGNoAMThxshKFD4yAXFADOwOpwDmkqACNt8jgFcEm%20hoGn5wvRwHA2cDhoD0DqADo30jgBMoARgAMflAIcHQQhPhEBCTQAEJ8dFCYonAA2gDWECBwPFDJALqsBEA)